# Possible to extract R packages installed from CRAN and Github, separately?

Tags: r, cran

I have a lot of `R` packages installed from `CRAN` as well as `GitHub`, and I was wondering how I could extract only those packages installed from CRAN, or only those from GitHub?

`installed.packages()` does not list any variables that I could use, as far as I understand...

Comment: Are you sure that the installation you would be doing would not require packages from both CRAN and GitHub?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen well, the IT team has asked me only to install packages from CRAN, stating those will be more thoroughly tested, than those at GitHub, which may have bugs. And I was attempting to programmatically extract all packages installed from CRAN...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
packages <- installed.packages()[,1]

packages.keep <- sapply(packages, function(x) {
                                     url <- packageDescription(x)$URL
                                     if (length(grep("github", x = url)) == 0) {
                                        return(FALSE)
                                     }
                                     else {
                                        return(TRUE)
                                     }
                                  })

packages[packages.keep]

> packages[packages.keep]
           curl      data.table             DBI        devtools           dplyr 
         "curl"    "data.table"           "DBI"      "devtools"         "dplyr" 
       evaluate        forecast         ggplot2           git2r       gridExtra 
     "evaluate"      "forecast"       "ggplot2"         "git2r"     "gridExtra" 
          Hmisc            httr           mailR         memoise            mime 
        "Hmisc"          "httr"         "mailR"       "memoise"          "mime" 
           plyr            R.oo         R.utils              R6            Rcpp 
         "plyr"          "R.oo"       "R.utils"            "R6"          "Rcpp" 
  RcppArmadillo        reshape2        roxygen2         RSQLite       rversions 
"RcppArmadillo"      "reshape2"      "roxygen2"       "RSQLite"     "rversions" 
         scales         whisker 
       "scales"       "whisker"
```

To verify this result, here is the URL information for the `ggplot2` package:

```
URL: http://ggplot2.org, https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2
```

It is clear that this package in part originated from GitHub, and it should appear in the list.  If you want to work with packages which did *not* come from GitHub, you can easily modify my code.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like:

```
local <- as.character(installed.packages()[,1])
mirror <- as.character(available.packages()[,1])
local[!(local %in% mirror)]
```

More refinement:

```
local <- installed.packages()[,c(1,3)]
mirror <- available.packages()[,c(1,2)]
dif.install <- local[!(local[,1] %in% mirror[,1]),]
same.install <- local[(local[,1] %in% mirror[,1]),]
dif.version <- same.install[!(same.install[,2] %in% mirror[,2]),]
out <- merge(dif.version, mirror[(mirror[,1] %in% dif.version[,1]),], by = "Package")
colnames(out) <- c("Package", "Other", "CRAN")
out
```

Gives for my installation:

```
     Package     Other  CRAN
1 data.table     1.9.5 1.9.4
2 manipulate 0.98.1103 1.0.1
3      Zelig     5.0-5 4.2-1
```

Comment: This won't discern between packages which were downloaded from GitHub and those which were not.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yeah, let me just time to refine

Comment: @Pascal thanks to you too! I certainly appreciate learning from you